# Not getting a txt token while hosting a website on firebase

Tags: firebase-hosting, custom-domain

I am trying to host a website on firebase . When I was Connecting my custom domain for the first time , I got txt token which I used in my DNS registrar and it got connected.
Then My website was not deploying on custom domain so I removed that .
Now whenever I connect to custom domain I don't get txt token and it get connected. I am not able to deploy on custom domain .

My firebase deploy command deploys on default domain provided by firebase .
Please help !!

When I deleted the domain on firebase and click on Add custom domain , verification should be there and I should get txt token for connection .